# How can I specify an ant target to run during the release:prepare goal?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

When using the maven release plugin I want to do some pre-work (via an ant tast) as part of the release build with the assurance that the same code base is used (so no commits sneak in between). I have an ant task that I want to call to do this, but I'm having the following issue:

inside my pom file:

```
            <configuration>
                <preparationGoals>antrun:run -Dtarget=${antTaskJarBuildXML} clean verify</preparationGoals>
            </configuration>
```

where ${antTaskJarBuildXML} is:

```
<target><ant antfile=\"../build.xml\" target=\"iv_dependency_build\" /></target>
```

When I run release:perform this is the log:

```
... 
[INFO] Not generating release POMs
[INFO] Executing goals 'antrun:run -Dtarget="<target><ant antfile=\"../build.xml\" target=\"iv_dependency_build\" /></target>" clean verify'...
[WARNING] Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has been configured for this MavenInvoker instance.
[INFO] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] [WARNING]
[INFO] [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.xactsites:iv:war:12.12.4.9
[INFO] [WARNING] The expression ${version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.version} instead.
[INFO] [WARNING]
[INFO] [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[INFO] [WARNING]
[INFO] [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[INFO] [WARNING]
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Building iv 12.12.4.9
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [WARNING] The artifact javax.xml:jaxrpc:jar:1.1 has been relocated to javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:1.1
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (default-cli) @ iv ---
[INFO] [INFO] No ant target defined - SKIPPED
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ iv ---
[INFO] [INFO] Deleting C:\dev\apps\iv\target
[INFO] [INFO]
...
```

And as shown in the log, I am told that no target is specified. I followed what I understood from the [ant run documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/run-mojo.html)

1. Am I missing something in how to pass in the target name?
2. Is this the best approach?
3. Is it a matter of escaping that I am missing? I'm on windows and this is the actual value defined for the xml (${antTaskJarBuildXML}):

   `"&lt;target&gt;&lt;ant antfile=\"../build.xml\" target=\"iv_dependency_build\" /&gt;&lt;/target&gt;"`

**EDIT**

@carlspring has given some great feedback (+1 on his answer), however, due to the nature of the problem where not everything is mavenized I couldn't get this working. Maven is expecting to be in control of the whole release process, but I need to perform an ant task (which creates dependencies needed for the build in question) beforehand. I also need to be assured that this prework task and the regular build are built against the same git tag/hash. My current solution is to sequentially do the steps that the release plugin would perform as discussed [here](http://www.insaneprogramming.be/?p=362). Through this I can create a git tag then do the maven build against that same git tag. If there are any better ideas out there please contribute!

Answer (score 2):

My suggestions would be for you to define a profile and have your ant-run definition in it.

The release plugin forks, meaning your command-line args will be ignored.

**UPDATE:**
*Try this:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project ...>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>

                <executions>
                     <execution>
                         <id>execute-prepare</id>
                         <!-- Set up your Ant stuff here -->
                         <goals>
                              <goal>prepare</goal>
                         </goals>
                         <configuration>
                             <!-- If you have args specific for your release, put them here: -->
                             <arguments>-Pant-run-release</arguments>
                             <releaseProfiles>ant-run-release</releaseProfiles>
                             <mavenExecutorId>forked-path</mavenExecutorId>
                         </configuration>
                     </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ant-run-release</id>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>execute-something</id>
                                <!-- Set up your Ant stuff here -->
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: I have some existing antrun executions defined that are part of the regular build process. How does using a profile affect the existing executions? Do they "merge" or does my profile overwrite the existing targets?

Comment: And a question that I'll likely ask after the above question is answered: how would I be able to have my pre-work task run only once, then when my project is built using the default lifecycle to not run.

I seems to me that by using profiles I'd have to add even more configuration (like setting properties like "doPreWorkTask" or "doRegularBuild" and putting an if on the targets) to differentiate between the two cases.

Comment: You could defined multiple `<executions/>` for your plugin's settings. Things merge in. Just make sure you use different `<id/>`-s because the last one will override the others. So, if you have a declaration of the antrun plugin both in a `<profile/>` and in a regular `<build/>` tag, things will merge in. Try it. :)

Comment: Please, further explain your second question. If you mean that you would like the ant tasks to only run during the `release:prepare` goal, then you can define an execution for the `prepare` goal in your `<build/>` and declare the respective settings in that section only, avoiding having them in the `perform` goal as well. (If this is what you mean).

Comment: Yeah, so let's see if I can make some sense. In the prepare goal the default phases run for the (i.e. the preparationGoals) is clean and verify. Verify will cause every previous phase in the lifecycle to be performed (inluding compile, to which I have attached other ant tasks). Then, If I attach this preWork task to say, the validate phase, then it will be run as part of the lifecycle. I notice that the release plugin builds the project 3 times or so. I don't want to (can't) have the preWork task be part of each of these other builds.

Comment: The release plugin builds the project three times: first to check that things build and the tests pass on your master/trunk/branch, then to perform the release from the respective tag it has created off the master/trunk/branch (this sets your artifact's version a fixed non-SNAPSHOT one), and once again (finally) from the master/trunk/branch, only this time bumped to a newer SNAPSHOT version. I hope this clears out the part it builds so many times.

Comment: Yes, but back to the original question, I don't want my prework task to run each of those three times, only the first time. If I set up a profile to do this and attach the task to the validate phase, then it will run 3 times. This was my original reasoning for trying to attach it to a preparation goal and not attach it to the lifecycle.

Comment: The profile is only activated during the release plugin's execution. You are a bit confused. The first build is built without activating any of the release profiles. The next two are. In the updated example, your ant task will get executed only in the prepare goal.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20703/discussion-between-noremac-and-carlspring)